What is the probability that I finish a massive doubles tournament, having played only teams that I've never seen either member of?
My problem is as follows:

I play a tournament where there are 116 opponents.
Opponents always occur in pairs. The pairs are made randomly from the 116, but fixed once the tournament starts.
Each opponent is in exactly one pair and cannot leave the pair.
My partner and I are not among the 116 and cannot be separated.
The pair consisting of myself and my partner and the 58 pairs of opponents are the only people in the tournament. The total number of individuals is therefore 118.
I have full choice over which pairs I face, but the pairs themselves are fixed
My preference is to only play against pairs where I have played against neither of the opponents.
Among the 116, there are only 31 opponents that I have never played against before.
I need to play against 4 pairs to finish the tournament. I cannot play against the same pair twice and cannot play against my own pair. The excess 54 pairs are not relevant to me finishing the tournament.
What is the probability that I will find 4 such pairs in one tournament?

Simulations suggest around a 60% chance, but I wanted to do this rigorously. I'm unfortunately extremely rusty. So far, I've tried:

Reasoning based on that there are 116 Choose 2 possible pairs and 31 Choose 2 pairs that fit my preference.
Anything involving subtracting 31 from 116 seems to be a total non-starter.
I tried to scale down the problem and solve it with far fewer players in the tournament, but it falls over once I ask myself "If there are N Choose 2 possible pairs, how many of those pairs form a valid tournament?".

This is reminiscent of both the Birthday problem and the Coupon Collector's problem, but I'm stumped.

Hi! I'm a little unclear on this, so let me ask some clarifying questions. First, can you confirm that there are $118$ total individuals in the tournament, including you and your partner? If so, out of the $116$ other people, are there $31$ people you have met before, or $31$ people you haven't met before? Finally, even though there seem to be $59$ pairs in the tournament total, you only need to win four matches to finish the tournament, yes?

@BrianTung Thanks. I've edited to clarify.

You and $53$ other pairs makes $108$ people. Where do the other $10$ come in?

@BrianTung Careless late-night arithmetic.

Assuming you just meant $58$ other pairs, can I assume you want an answer to the following question: If the $116$ other players are paired up at random, what is the probability that there exist at least four pairs drawn exclusively from the $31$ players I've never encountered?

@BrianTung Yes. Exactly that.

I think I can provide an answer. In the meantime, you might [edit] into your original post why you want the question answered. Is it a situation you've encountered as an actual player?

@BrianTung It is. I'll make the edit tomorrow. Sleep calls.

As in many cases where we want the probability that at least $n$ objects exist, where $n$ is relatively small, we can solve the problem more easily by finding instead the probability that there are at most $n-1$ objects, and then subtracting that probability from $1$.
Therefore, the probability we want is
\begin{align}
P(\text{at least $4$ unknown pairs})
    & = 1-\sum_{k=0}^3 P(\text{exactly $k$ unknown pairs}) \\
    & = 1-\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{\binom{58}{k}\binom{58-k}{31-2k}2^{31-2k}}
                            {\binom{116}{31}} \\
    & = 1-\frac{995\,766\,994\,731\,008}{2\,722\,305\,712\,734\,563} \rule[-1ex]{0ex}{5ex} \\
    & = \frac{1\,726\,538\,718\,003\,555}{2\,722\,305\,712\,734\,563}
      \approx 0.63422 \rule[-1ex]{0ex}{5ex} 
\end{align}
The expression in the second line can be obtained as follows: Imagine an array of $58$ dominos, each with a left cell and a right cell, all initially empty. We want to put $31$ pips in those $116$ cells such that there are exactly $k$ dominos with a double pip. These represent the pairs that consist only of players you've never encountered.
The number of ways to do that is

the number of ways to select the $k$ double-pip dominos, which is $\binom{58}{k}$
times the number of ways to select the $31-2k$ distinct dominos to put the remaining $31-2k$ pips, which is $\binom{58-k}{31-2k}$
times the number of ways to pick left or right for each of those $31-2k$ pips, which is $2^{31-2k}$

The total number of ways to place the $31$ pips amongst the $116$ cells is, of course, $\binom{116}{31}$. The ratio of these gives the probability of exactly $k$ unknown pairs; summing these from $k = 0$ to $3$ and subtracting from $1$ gives, indeed, a value close to $60$ percent.

Incidentally, the most likely number of unknown pairs is $k = 4$, with a probability of about $26$ percent. Next is $k = 3$ ($22$ percent), then $k = 5$ ($21$ percent), and then $k = 2$ and $k = 6$ (both about $11$ percent, but not exactly equal to each other).
